# Kubernetes NodePort not accesible from outside

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, bitnami

I'm trying to use the latest bitnami postgres chart to deploy postgres to a local kubernetes cluster (mac os, docker desktop 4.4.2, kubernetes 1.22.5):
https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql

I have set the node port:

```
primary:
  service:
    # Kubernetes Service type
    type: NodePort
    nodePorts:
      # Node port for PostgreSQL
      postgresql: '30000'
```

the service is visible:

```
NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/postgres-nodeport      NodePort    10.111.195.149   <none>        5432:30000/TCP   9m56s
```

but I cant access it from outside, eg:

```
psql -h localhost -p 30000 -U myusername -d mydatabase
```

but I think it is configured correctly, because when I execute port-forward postgres is available:

```
kubectl port-forward pod/postgres-nodeport-0 30000:5432
```

Comment: What happens if you do psql -h 10.111.195.149 -p 30000 -U myusername -d mydatabase

Comment: @AydinK.
psql: error: could not connect to server: Network is unreachable

Comment: what do you mean by localhost?  Are you doing this from the node the pod is running on?

Comment: can you add this output in your description also? `kubectl get nodes -owide`

Comment: TheFool
I'm executing this commang (psql) from the local terminal

@Emon46
output of your command:
```NAME             STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE         KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
docker-desktop   Ready    control-plane,master   54m   v1.22.5   192.168.65.4   <none>        Docker Desktop   5.10.76-linuxkit   docker://20.10.12
```
PS: I found a solution, check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
You need to set the port to higher than 30000, e.g. 30001
but its strange, because earlier it worked with port 30000, and the documentation says that the port range is 30000-32767

Answer (score 1):

The Docker Desktop CINC has the `vpnkit-controller` so if you set a service to use a `LoadBalancer` it exposes it via your local machine:

```
primary:
    service: 
      type: "LoadBalancer"
```

It is also assigned a random NodePort but the `vpnkit` will expose the default port of 5432 on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call with node ip.
The format should be `NodeIP` of the Node where you are running your pods and the `NodePort`. [Ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)

The Template to call NodePort  service from outside the cluster is like this.

```
<NodeIP>:<NodePort>
```

Try this one:

```
psql -h 192.168.65.4 -p 30000 -U myusername -d mydatabase
```

Answer (score -2):

Nodeport only exposes the service on the nodes at the specified port. It does not expose it to the public. You need to configure ingress or load balancer to expose the service to the outside world.

Comment: A NodePort-type service is accessible on the specified port on every node's IP address or DNS name, from outside the cluster, assuming the nodes are reachable.

Comment: That was my point, we don't assume that the Nodes are reachable. Accessing services from individual nodes is not a best practice, as nodes might go down, and new nodes added by auto-scaling. So adding a loadbalancer or ingress, is the more reliable way to access the service from outside.